# CORS issue with PowerBI API

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to generate an embed token for a report by calling below endpoint but it thorws me CORS issue.

> Failed to load
>   https://api.powerbi.com/myorg/groups//reports//GenerateToken:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Is there any setting in power bi dashboard or enable CORS and set allowed origins?

Answer (score -1):

you shouldn't get cors issue if you called power api in server side code.
No setting changes required in powerbi dashboard.
Please share code snippet if you can.

Answer (score -3):

CORS is a browser security feature that disallows cross site referencing. Hence there isn't any setting on the PowerBI part to get it fixed. We earlier worked with the REST APIs but faced CORS issue on almost every browser. Using the [CORS plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) for Chrome fixed the issue. But can't expect every user to install the client side plugin.

As a work around, we took the WebAPI approach, wherein our client side script hit the WebAPI endpoint, communicated with the PowerBI service to return the report. To overcome the CORS issue this way, add a reference to **System.Web.Cors** in the **WebConfig.cs** file found under **App_Start** folder and add the line `config.EnableCors();`

In the Controller, decorate the method with EnableCors as shown below and that should resolve your problem:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.MyControllers
{
    public class MyAPIController : ApiController
    { 
       [HttpPOST]
       [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
       public string getData()
       {
          return "This Works !";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not related to OP not knowing about whats CORS is. The API mentioned here is part of powerbi service hosted by Microsoft and is not written by the OP.